# iTunes Store operation failed. No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier ‘org.cocoapods.Alamofire’ is correct

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I’m trying to upload binary to iTunesConnect using Xcode8.3.
There are around `10 cocoa pods (Alamofire, SideMenuController, DropDown etc)` in my project.

However, while uploading I’m getting strange error related to bundle identifier.

**iTunes Store operation failed. No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier ‘org.cocoapods.Alamofire’ is correct.**

[image: Screenshot]

I tried some fix mentioned below :

1. Renamed `‘org.cocoapods.Alamofire`’ bundle id of Alamofire Cocoapods to `com.companyName.AppName`
2. Renamed `‘org.cocoapods.Alamofire’` bundle id of Alamofire Cocoapods to `com.companyName.AppName.Alamofire` (Even registered new bundle id on iTunes Connect with com.companyName.AppName.Alamofire id)
3. Deleted `‘org.cocoapods.Alamofire’` bundle id but reappeared

Any other quick fix?

Comment: Do you have an app on iTunesConnect same as your App Bundle ID?

Comment: @Imad : I've an app record on iTunesConnect with same App bundle Id...com.companyName.AppName. Cross verified this multiple times. I'm getting bundle id issue for Cocoapods being used.

Comment: I've experienced several challenges while uploading archives the last two weeks. Have you tried using the Application Loader-app?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey are you using pods or custom library ?

Comment: @Jack : I'm using available CocoaPods...like SideMenuController, Alamofire etc

Comment: @IvanLeHjelmeland : When I upload using Application Loader then it prompts an error releated to Provision profile..event though it is correct.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey are you adding pods files in target Folder ?

Comment: @Jack : You mean...I'm using Pods..right? Then...yes. I'm using Pods

Comment: @JayprakashDubey then uncheck code sign for pods

Comment: checkout your bundle version, if you have already uploaded once the you need to update version whenever you upload bundle again

Comment: i am stuck with same thing did you find any solution?

Comment: @PulkitKumarSingh : For me the issue was with third party library. I removed unwanted stuff from that library and it worked!

Comment: unwanted stuff as in?... two days back i uploaded the same application without any hassle

Comment: @Jayprakash Dubey  i did not change anything  next day it started uploading i guess apple is just messing with us .

Comment: @PulkitKumarSingh : There maybe something strange factor like your system was restarted or some bug on iTunesConnect might be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this situation two days ago and I solved it with simple steps:

1- go to iTunes Connect site

2- My Apps

3- press ( + ) sign and choose New app --> fill in all fields

[image]

4- then try to upload your app again.

Answer (score 1):

Deintegrate pods and then reinstall pods.

```
pod deintegrate && pod setup && pod install
```

Then create archive and upload it on iTunes connect.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my computer did the trick in my case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Well, the actual question is "Any other quick fix?" – which is what I have provided here.